# sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am trying to put some data into an SQLite DB using SQLAlchemy.

The JSON data I am trying to put into table:

```
[{'type': 'paragraph', 'children': [{'text': 'A line of text in a paragraph.'}]}]
```

My model:

```py
import datetime
from . import db, ma

class Books(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'books'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False) 

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

class ContentSchema(ma.Schema):
        fields = ('content')
```

My view:

```py
@main_blueprint.route('/add_book', methods=['POST'])
def add_book():

    books_data = request.get_json()

    new_book = Books(content=books_data)

    db.session.add(new_book)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'Success', 201
```

The error I am recieving is the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO books (content) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ([{'type': 'paragraph', 'children': [{'text': 'A line of text in a paragraph.'}]}],)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

How can I put JSON data into the database?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `content` field expects text

```
books_data = request.get_json()
new_book = Books(content=books_data)
```

Here, it's being fed a JSON object.

```
import json
...
next_book = Books(content=json.dumps(books_data))
```

should fix that. You'll need to use `json.loads()` after retrieving `content` to reconstitute a JSON object, assuming that's what you'll need.